# Where was Ben Solo conceived?

Tags: star-wars, princess-leia, han-solo, star-wars-aftermath, star-wars-bloodline

Okay, I know how creepy this question looks, but I swear there's an actual reason behind it.

We know that Ben Solo was born in 5 ABY to Leia and Han.  In the canon novel *Aftermath: Life Debt* from 2016, Han reflects on Leia's pregnancy.  He then comments that he's not surprised about her actually being pregnant, as he recalls "nights in the Endor forest" with his wife.  In the canon novel *Bloodline,* published only a month prior, however, Leia recounts the events differently.  She thinks back to her younger days with Han, and what they got up to specifically on the Millenium Falcon, ending with how that time on the Falcon is likely where she became pregnant.

Technically, *Life Debt* was published after *Bloodline,* but it seems strange for such a small detail to be conflicting.  Can *Life Debt* be considered the official account, since it came out first?

Comment: Why does this conflict?  It recounts 2 different individuals perception when Ben was conceived.  Obviously both can't be correct - but how often are couples able to pinpoint exactly when conception occured?